# Some sql queries work in terminal but not with db_query() function in Drupal 6 Why..?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following mysql table called "test".

[image]

lets say it has the data as follows,

[image]

Now i would like to get the age of the user, for that I use the following query..

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(DOB, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(DOB, '00-%m-%d')) AS age from test where user_name = 'akshaynhegde';
```

It works and returns age 21. (this is when I run the query in the terminal)

But, when I use the the following code in Drupal 6, It returns nothing...!!

```
    global $user;
    $uname = $user->name;

$sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(DOB, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(DOB, '00-%m-%d')) AS age from test where user_name = '%s'";

$age = db_result(db_query($sql,$uname));
```

I tried all the possibilities such as using `db_fetch_array()` , `db_fetch_object()` and separately executed `$result = db_query($sql,$uname)` and then passed $result to `db_result()`..

But NOTHING WORKS..! Why..????

Well, FYI other simple queries work.. for example the following, it works.

```
$sql = "select DOB from test where user_name = '%s'";
$dob = db_result(db_query($sql,$uname));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've got no experience with either Drupal or PHP, but I'm sure your problem is the `%Y`, `%m` and `%d` you have in your query string. You'll need to escape thhose so only %s is left.

According to [%d modifier in db_query not wanted](http://drupal.org/node/100846) you escape them by writing two `%` instead of just one.

So you query string should look like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(DOB, '%%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%%m-%%d') < DATE_FORMAT(DOB, '00-%%m-%%d')) AS age from test where user_name = '%s'";
```

Answer (score 0):

With Drupal your table name should be enclosed by {} brackets.
and you can also put your query into one line like this:

```
$dob = db_result(db_query(SELECT `DOB` FROM {test} WHERE user_name = '%s'",$uname);
```

The db_query itself works with printf type format, so its easier to stick to using that and becomes less confusing when doing more complex sql queries through the drupal db api.

Comment: I only addressed your simple query just to explain the concept of the db api