# MySQL FORMAT_DATE %d returning '0'

Tags: mysql, date, format

I'm having trouble with MySQL format_date, and don't understand why. I have the following as part of my code:

```
date_format(NOW() + INTERVAL 3 DAY, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

which seems to work fine, except for the fact that regardless of the date I choose, the %d is returning as a single zero ('0'). If I change %d to %e I can get the correct date, but I'm using this to compare dates, so I need the leading zero for numbers below 10. Is this a database setting, or am I missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I feel like it has to be something in the db, because when I simplify the query to this:

```
$q = "SELECT date_format(NOW() + INTERVAL 3 DAY, '%Y-%m-%d') as 'today' from content_field_date LIMIT 1";
```

'today' prints out as '2012-03-0'

Meanwhile, this:

```
$q = "SELECT date_format(NOW() + INTERVAL 3 DAY, '%Y-%m-%e') as 'today' from content_field_date LIMIT 1";
```

correctly returns '2012-03-17'

Zeth

Comment: odd. If I run `SELECT date_format(NOW() + INTERVAL 3 DAY, '%Y-%m-%d')` it displays properly. I wonder if it has to do with your locale?

Comment: Can you show the full query? This shouldn't happen.

Comment: Its does not show `0` here too.  if your target is to compare dates you can do it in mysql too.

Comment: Strange. Does this happen, too, if you put other number, say `+ INTERVAL 17 DAY` ?

Comment: (irrelevant to the error): The `as 'today'` should be `as today` or `as \`today\``.

Comment: What are the character set and collation of the table and the connection?

Comment: @ypercube - yes, it does happen with different intervals

Comment: Then it could be a character set/collation issue. I can't find any other explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHat you describe should not happen. You either found a MySQL bug or you are doing something wrong.

If you only want to compare dates, you can do that inside MySQL and you probably shouldn't be using `DATE_FORMAT()` at all. You can use this to get a date:

```
DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

or:

```
(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

Comment: I'm comparing the current date with a field in the database that's formated 'YYYY-MM-DD', hence the need for formatting, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Is the column `CHAR` and formatted like this or is it a `DATE` column?

Comment: In either case `column < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 3 DAY` should work fine. But use the `DATE` type for storing dates. Otherwise, you may get data like `2011-17-48` in there. Or even `2011-AA-0B`. Or whatever.

Comment: Never found out why %d wouldn't work, but removing the DATE_FORMAT all together appears to have gotten me the desired result. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same issue today, based on your table name of "content_field_date" I'm assuming Drupal was being used.  The answer to this can be found here:

[Some sql queries work in terminal but not with db_query() function in Drupal 6 Why..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256263/some-sql-queries-work-in-terminal-but-not-with-db-query-function-in-drupal-6-w)

and here:
http://drupal.org/node/100846

in that the percent signs need to be escaped, so the correct query should be:

```
$q = "SELECT date_format(NOW() + INTERVAL 3 DAY, '%%Y-%%m-%%d') as 'today' from content_field_date LIMIT 1";
```